# Will a struct be garbage collected if there's no references to the struct but the struct contains a pointer to a global object?

Tags: go, garbage-collection

As the title says, say if a struct A contains a pointer to a global object globalB:

```
type struct B {
  // fields of B
}

type struct A {
  pb *B
}

var globalB B

func newA() *A {
  a := &A{
    pb: &globalB,
  }
  return a
}
```

we get a reference to A after calling `newA()`, and if at some time we've done with A and there's no references to it, will the A struct created in `newA()` be garbage collected?

Comment: Of course. That's how garbage collection works. Please note that a pointer to an A is _not_ a "reference", it's just a pointer to ...

Comment: @Volker But in this case, A is not reachable from the root right? Just because its member field point to a global variable, A is not garbage collected?

Comment: No. the `a` is collected. For being able to be collected by the GC it doesn't matter whether the object to be collected contains pointers or not (and if it contains where these point to). May I ask what actual problem you are trying to solve or understand?

Comment: @Volker I have a websocket server application, it creates a client struct for every client connection it receives, the client struct holds: 1. a pointer to the websocket server struct, 2. a pointer to a underlying `Conn` object(provided by the gorilla/websocket package), 3. other maps and channels. The client struct is added to the server struct's map, when the client disconnects, it's removed from the map. Now the program got memory leak, the heap profile shows that the leak occurs at the client struct, but I've checked many times no other places hold the client struct, just the server's map.

Comment: The websocket server struct is long-lived, so I'm guessing whether it because the client struct holds the pointer to this server struct which seems not the cause now.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand what you are talking about. You seem to have issues with memory. You seem to believe there is a leak (which is **unlikely** as it's almost impossible to actually "leak" memory without unsafe or cgo). In any case: In the code you posted `a` in newA is eligible for collection once _it_ _itself_ is no longer used or pointed to.

Comment: My assumptions are: You are measuring "memory consumption" wrong (most likely), or something is actually pinning some things in the sense "use" or "point to" (less likely, possible) or you use some library which has some caveats you did not honour (think of "reuse this instead of recreating").